# How can I change the contents of one QComboBox depending on another QComboBox in PyQt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qcombobox

I write program on python3 that will calculate thermodynamic properties. This is piece of GUI

[image]

"Выбранное вещество" is a selected substance like 1-Butene, water, ammonia and etc.

"Первый параметр" is a first parameter. User will choose parameters like pressure, temperature, density and etc, and unit of measurement like Pa, MPa, bar (if it's pressure) and etc. So I don't know one thing: i want that if user chose pressure('Давление (P)') in top combobox, depending on this, suitable units of measure were chosen in small combobox.

What have i already done: create 2 files

- testGUI.py - there is all GUI (i create in Qt Designer)
- CalcProp.py - there is all logic of program (classes and functions)

So in **CalcProp.py** i wrote class that contains function that returns the list of parameters:

```
class ChooseParams():
   def paramList(self):
      P = 'Pressure (P)'
      T = 'Temperature (T)'
      D = 'Density (D)'
      V = 'Volume (V)'
      H = 'Enthalpy (h)'
      S = 'Entropy (s)'
      Q = 'Vapor quality (x)'

      allParams = [P, T, D, V, H, S, Q]

      return allParams
```

After i created class that contains function that selects unit of measurements:

```
class ChooseUnitOfMeasurement():
    def unitOfMeasurement(self, parameter):

        #Pressure
        Pa = 'Па'
        kPa = 'кПа'
        MPa = 'МПа'
        PressureUnitList = [Pa, kPa, MPa]

        #Temperature
        kelvin = 'К'
        degC = '°C'
        degF = '°F'
        tempUnitList = [kelvin, degC, degF]

        #Enthalpy
        kJdivKg = 'кДж/кг'
        JdivKg = 'Дж/кг'
        enthalpyUnitList = [kJdivKg, JdivKg]

        #Entropy
        kJdivKgKel = 'кДж/(кг-К)'
        JdivKgKel = 'Дж/(кг-К)'
        entropyUnitList = [kJdivKgKel, JdivKgKel]

        #Density
        kgDivMeter = 'кг/м^3'

        #Volume
        meterDivKg = 'м^3/кг'

        #Vapor quality
        vaporQuality = '--'


        if parameter == 'Pressure (P)':
            return PressureUnitList
        elif parameter == 'Temperature (T)':
            return tempUnitList
        elif parameter == 'Density (D)':
            return kgDivMeter
        elif parameter == 'Volume (V)':
            return meterDivKg
        elif parameter == 'Enthalpy (h)':
            return enthalpyUnitList
        elif parameter == 'Entropy (s)':
            return entropyUnitList
        else:
            return vaporQuality
```

in **testGUI.py**

```
#Creation combobox for selection first parameter
self.comboBoxInputFirstParam = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.groupBoxFirstParam)
#put parameters
self.comboBoxInputFirstParam.addItems(CalcProp.ChooseParams.paramList(self))

#Creation combobox for selection unit of measurement (first parameter)
self.comboBoxInputFirstParamUnit = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.groupBoxFirstParam)
#get text of first combobox
firstParameter = self.comboBoxInputFirstParam.currentText()
#Depending on the content of the first one, add the required list / value in the combobox with units of measurement.
self.comboBoxInputFirstParamUnit.addItems(CalcProp.ChooseUnitOfMeasurement.unitOfMeasurement(self, firstParameter))
```

Everything works, but that's only when the program starts, when I change the pressure to another value, then unit of measurement does not change. **And I'm interested in how to change the contents of one combobox depending on another in real time.**

Comment: what is `self.groupBoxFirstParam`?

Comment: it's name of object QGroupBox (orange rectangle "Первый параметр" in the picture )

Comment: It is not necessary to use `self` as an attribute in the methods, this is the responsibility of the class, since it internally passes the instance. Try my code.

Comment: Did you work my solution?

Comment: @eyllanesc i try to do you solution, but i have error:

Comment: QObject::connect: Cannot connect QComboBox::currentTextChanged(QString) to (null)::onCurrentTextChanged(QString)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/artskadin/PycharmProjects/Lomonosov/MainDir/mainFile.py", line 9, in <module>
    uw.setupUi(w)
  File "/Users/artskadin/PycharmProjects/Lomonosov/MainDir/testGui.py", line 253, in setupUi
    @eyllanesc self.comboBoxInputFirstParam.currentTextChanged['QString'].connect(self.onCurrentTextChanged)
TypeError: connect() failed between currentTextChanged(QString) and onCurrentTextChanged()

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @eyllanesc I was looking for where I made a mistake, and I was afraid of showing myself stupid and interrogating you

Comment: Try again my code, the problem is of versions of pyqt5

Comment: No one is stupid, we are all to learn.

Comment: Did you run my modified solution?

Comment: AttributeError: module 'PyQt5.QtCore' has no attribute 'QString'

Comment: Now try please, do you have teamviewer?

Comment: no, but i can install it right now

Comment: @eyllanesc do you have a telegram. i'm **artskadin**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the signal `currentTextChanged`, this is activated every time you choose an item, returning the text, we must also validate if it is a list or a single element. All of the above is implemented in the following code:

```
    [...]
    self.comboBoxInputFirstParam = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.groupBoxFirstParam)
    self.comboBoxInputFirstParamUnit = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.groupBoxFirstParam)
    self.comboBoxInputFirstParam.currentTextChanged.connect(self.onCurrentTextChanged)

    self.comboBoxInputFirstParam.addItems(CalcProp.ChooseParams().paramList())

def onCurrentTextChanged(self, text):
    self.comboBoxInputFirstParamUnit.clear()
    elements = CalcProp.ChooseUnitOfMeasurement().unitOfMeasurement(str(text))
    if isinstance(elements, list):
        self.comboBoxInputFirstParamUnit.addItems(elements)
    else:
        self.comboBoxInputFirstParamUnit.addItem(elements)
```